# Simplify $\log\left(1+\frac{x_i^2}{\nu}\right)$ with a $\log(1+x)$ rule?

Tags: random-variables, logarithms

How can the following logarithm be simplified? Is there a $\log(1+x)$ rule to use?

$$ \log\left(1+\frac{x_i^2}{\nu}\right) = ?$$

Comment: There's no $\log(1+x)$ rule.

Answer (score 1):

If the $1$ was not there, we could have written the expression as
$$2\log x_i-\log\nu$$
provided that the variables are positive. But the $1$ prevents this, though it does mean we get a Taylor series expansion
$$\log\left(1+\frac{x_i^2}\nu\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(x_i^2/\nu)^n}n$$

Answer (score 0):

There is no realy usefull simplification... But if was about approximation, you could  use the fact that
$$
\log(1+x) = x- \frac{x^2}{2} + O(x^3)
$$

to say that, for small $x$,
$$
\log(1+\frac{x_i^2}{\nu}) \approx \frac{x_i^2}{\nu}-\frac 12 \left(\frac{x_i^2}{\nu}\right)^2 = \frac{x_i^2}{\nu}\left(1- \frac{x_i^2}{2 \nu}\right).
$$